# Throws an Exception when I add `<aop:before>` to beans.xml

Tags: spring

This is my Main.java

```java
import org.springframework.context.*;
import org.springframework.context.support.*;

public class Main{
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ApplicationContext context = 
      new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("./beans.xml");

    Cat cat = (Cat) context.getBean("cat");
    cat.sleep();
  }
}

class Cat{
  public void sleep(){
    System.out.println("cat is sleeping.");
  }
}
class Timer{
  public void begain(){
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
  }
  public void stop(){
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
  }
}
```

and this is my `beans.xml` for ApplicationContext.

```xml
<!-- omit some links -->
<beans>
  <bean id="cat" class="Cat"></bean>
  <bean id="t1" class="Timer"></bean>

  <aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="t1">
      <aop:pointcut id="cat_sleep" 
          expression="execution(* *.sleep(..))" />
      <aop:before
          pointcut-ref="cat_sleep"
          method="begain" />
    </aop:aspect>
  </aop:config>
</beans>
```

I want to call `Timer_Instance.begain` before `Cat_Instance.sleep`,
But when I try to exxcute this code, it thrown a very long exception, I no idea about this.

```
Feb 28, 2019 4:34:58 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cat' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5b1669c0' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5b1669c0': Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1de0aca6] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cat' defined in class path resource [beans.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5b1669c0' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5b1669c0': Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1de0aca6] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
        at Main.main(Main.java:6)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5b1669c0' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5b1669c0': Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1de0aca6] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:327)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:676)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1171)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:91)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:109)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1081)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5b1669c0': Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1de0aca6] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:159)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1171)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:312)
        ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3090)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2316)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:154)
        ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
        ... 37 more
```

But if I delete `aop.before` form beans.xml, the code will be fine.

```xml
<beans>
  <bean id="cat" class="Cat"></bean>
  <bean id="t1" class="Timer"></bean>

  <aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="t1">
      <aop:pointcut id="cat_sleep" 
          expression="execution(* *.sleep(..))" />
      <!--<aop:before
          pointcut-ref="cat_sleep"
          method="begain" />-->
    </aop:aspect>
  </aop:config>
</beans>
```

I was really confused, I am following a book about spring, I can not find some problem with my `beans.xml`.

I am using Spring-5.1.5.

[image]

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong. `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint` is quite expliciti in what is missing. The aspectj library.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, @M.Deinum

I miss two dependencies of Spring. I should download them from

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.2
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.9.2

and add these to my classpath.